# Chart monthly average NDVI values

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am hoping to obtain monthly averages for NDVI derived from Landsat data and then produce a line chart.

I have succeeded in cloudmasking Landsat 8 and adding an NDVI band.

Working with code suggested in another post I was able to create an image collection with one NDVI value per month for 5 years.

Now however, when I try and chart this image collection there is no "system:time_start" available so I cannot produce a time series.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Maybe I have to go about calculating the monthly mean NDVI values in a different way.

My code is below.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7c0abe5c696a4aa246647f4b34e2f48c

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by simply replacing the line `.set('month', m).set('year', y)` by `.set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1))` in your function calculating `byMonthYear`.

Using `mean()` method (or other reducing methods such as `median()`, `max()`, etc.) on ImageCollection would result in the loss of all image's properties including `system:time_start`. This is fairly reasonable as Google Earth Engine has no idea from which image it should take properties.

The above fix just manually adds `system:time_start` property back to the `mean` image. This property should hold a `ee.Date` object (I just made it the first day of the month).